# Vue. Проблема с циклом v-for in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

наткнулся на такую проблему в одном из template ов есть цикл v-for in.
`v-for="(car,index) in cars"`. Проблема в том что цикл работает корректно если между car ом и index ом нету пробела, а мой редактор ставит между ними пробел и выводится ошибка

```
> 1 | for(let [(car,]index) in cars);
    |          ^  vue/no-parsing-error
  21:11  error  Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive  vue/valid-v-for
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что содержится в переменной `cars` ?

Comment: ``` 
const car = (id, name, model, price, owner, year, phone, image) => ({
  id,
  name,
  model,
  price,
  owner,
  year,
  phone,
  image
})



const cars = [
  car('BMW', 'M5 F90', '250.000', 'Nodir', 2020, '+7 489 934 77 89', './images/BMW.jpg'),
  car( 'Nissan', 'GTR', '120.000', 'Angella', 2016, '+7 593 645 22 12', './images/Nissan_GTR.jpg'),
  car('Mercedes', 'AMG GT63', '220.000', 'John', 2019, '+7 593 324 67 12', './images/Mercedes.jpg'),
  car( 'Mercedes', 'AMG GT63', '220.000', 'John', 2019, '+7 593 324 67 12', './images/Mercedes.jpg')
]
```